# How to divide three numbers to another three numbers in all six possible ways with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, probability

I have two arrays, each consisting of three numbers that actually refer to the dimensions of two boxes.

```
const boxOne = [boxOneWidth=20, boxOneLength=40, boxOneHeight=60];
const boxTwo = [boxTwoWidth=2, boxTwoLength=4, boxTwoHeight=5];
```

I want to divide the dimesions of boxOne to the dimensions of boxTwo. But I need to use the six possible scenerio in terms of order to help myself to do a more complex calculation.

To be more specific, I need to do the following calculations in a shorter way as I will have to write tons of code otherwise.

```
const boxOneOpt1 = (boxOne[0]/boxTwo[0]) * (boxOne[1]/boxTwo[1]) * (boxOne[2]/boxTwo[2]);
const boxOneOpt2 = (boxOne[0]/boxTwo[0]) * (boxOne[1]/boxTwo[2]) * (boxOne[2]/boxTwo[1]);
const boxOneOpt3 = (boxOne[0]/boxTwo[1]) * (boxOne[1]/boxTwo[0]) * (boxOne[2]/boxTwo[2]);
const boxOneOpt4 = (boxOne[0]/boxTwo[1]) * (boxOne[1]/boxTwo[2]) * (boxOne[2]/boxTwo[0]);
const boxOneOpt5 = (boxOne[0]/boxTwo[2]) * (boxOne[1]/boxTwo[0]) * (boxOne[2]/boxTwo[1]);
const boxOneOpt6 = (boxOne[0]/boxTwo[2]) * (boxOne[1]/boxTwo[1]) * (boxOne[2]/boxTwo[0]);
```

I know, it is pure javascript. Itried to solve it using for loops but somehow I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a naive approach to the issue, but this should work:

```js
/**
 * @description return all possible combinations of items in the given array
 * @param { array } xs - array of items
 * @return { array[array] } - permutations
 */
function perm(xs) {
  let ret = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i = i + 1) {
    let rest = perm(xs.slice(0, i).concat(xs.slice(i + 1)));

    if (!rest.length) {
      ret.push([xs[i]]);
    } else {
      for (let j = 0; j < rest.length; j = j + 1) {
        ret.push([xs[i]].concat(rest[j]));
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

const boxOne = [(boxOneWidth = 20), (boxOneLength = 40), (boxOneHeight = 60)];
const boxTwo = [(boxTwoWidth = 2), (boxTwoLength = 4), (boxTwoHeight = 5)];

// get all possible arrangements of the indexes
/*
  Here each number in the array(being passed in as the parameter) corresponds to an index in just one array
  So, if you have three arrays to perform the calculation on, it'll be 
  something like this: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
  This can be easily auto-generated based on the arrays.
*/
const arrangements = perm([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]);
let finalResult = {};
arrangements.forEach((arrangement, index) => {
  const result = (boxOne[arrangement[0]] / boxTwo[arrangement[1]]) * (boxOne[arrangement[2]] / boxTwo[arrangement[3]]) * (boxOne[arrangement[4]] / boxTwo[arrangement[5]])
  finalResult[`boxOneOpt${index+1}`] = result
})
console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all 6 results are always the same, you just need one calculation. For example: `const boxOneOpt123456 = (boxOne[0]*boxOne[1]*boxOne[2]) / (boxTwo[0]*boxTwo[1]*boxTwo[2]);`

Comment: Thank you for your response. For this example, I selected even numbers for the sake of simplicity. But since there may be odd numbers and I need to floor every single calculation and use them later, the results will not be the same. Thank you anyway.